# Different click listeners for single image

Tags: android, image, clicklistener

How to create multiple click listeners for one image in android?
I have one body image. When I click head it should go to head click listener and if I click legs it should go to leg click listener. How to differentiate like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a Image map, something like this::

```
<map name="map-name">
<area shape="rect" coords="135,180,200,185" href="webpage1.html">
<area shape="circle" coords="49,300,42" href="webpage2.html">
<area shape="poly" coords="24,35,55,20,90,42,91,80,60,105" href="webpage3.html">
</map>
<img src="image.gif" usemap="#map-name">
```

Answer (score 1):

how system comes to no you click head or anythin other?

i think you can do a hack

- apply click event listener for whole image
- and take event.x and event.y to determine which part you clicked  and based on that call a function..